# WPF doesn't want to go full screen

Tags: wpf, window, toggle, scale, fullscreen

**Hello!**
I was making my own minimize and fullscreen buttons but ran into a problem.
I have some window:

```
<Window x:Class="LeagueOfTeamsUI.Views.GameWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeagueOfTeamsUI.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    
    x:Name="GameMainWindow" Title="GameWindow" AllowDrop="True"
    MinWidth="1440" MinHeight="810" WindowStyle="None"
    
    MouseLeftButtonDown="GameMainWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown"  Background="{x:Null}"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" AllowsTransparency="True">
```

And have toggle button, to make window fullscreen:

```
private void CheckedFullScreenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GameMainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
private void UncheckedFullScreenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GameMainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
private void GameMainWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DragMove();
    }
```

But when I use this button - the window stays the same size. It only sticks to the top left corner.

I found that if I manually drag the window to the edge of the screen once (on Win10 this stretches the window to half the screen), then nothing changes and the window also sticks to the corner. But if you repeat this action, the window is stretched to half the screen. After that, the fullscreen button works correctly while the app is running.

Please show me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `SizeToContent` property. You set it to `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` which means that:

> // Automatically resize height and width relative to content

> this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;

While your window maximizes the content size does not change, and the window size will stay the same.

Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.sizetocontent?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Remove that property and it should work.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to thank you in the right way.
So thank you a lot! :D